# Vertica Copy Statement - Null Parameter with Multiple Null Strings

Tags: vertica

I'm trying to import a pipe-delimited text file into a table in Vertica. The string representation of NULL in the text file is "[NULL]". The problem with the file, though, is that a lot of the fields with NULL have trailing whitespace as well.

https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPYParameters.htm

It certainly doesn't look like it's possible, but is there any way to pass a regex to the null parameter?

Any other ideas besides a bunch of post COPY updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transformation in the COPY statement, like in this scenario:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id   INT
, nam  VARCHAR(32)
, dob  DATE
)
;
COPY foo (
  id
, nam_in FILLER VARCHAR
, nam AS CASE WHEN TRIM(nam_in) <> '[NULL]' THEN nam_in END
, dob_in FILLER VARCHAR
, dob AS CASE WHEN TRIM(dob_in) <> '[NULL]' THEN dob_in::DATE END
)
FROM STDIN DELIMITER '|' ;
    42|Arthur Dent  |[NULL]
    43|Ford Prefect |1957-04-01
    44|[NULL]       |2021-01-01
\.

\pset null (null)
SELECT * FROM foo;
-- out Null display is "(null)".                                                                                                                                                       
-- out  id |      nam      |    dob     
-- out ----+---------------+------------
-- out  42 | Arthur Dent   | (null)
-- out  43 | Ford Prefect  | 1957-04-01
-- out  44 | (null)        | 2021-01-01
```

You can import in-line from a script using STDIN, but you can also use a file for this exercise ...

Comment: Awesome, thank you!